# How to get a background-image in a jQuery .text.css position

Tags: jquery, css

With this line:

```
$('<p>').appendTo('#map_div')
    .text('MERCURY')
    .css({
        position:'absolute',
        top:'100px',
        left:'70px'
    });
```

I will get the text `MERCURY` on a given position on a image.

How do I code this in a CSS `background-image` or a `color` behind this text?

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zAJvx/2/

Comment: `backgroundImage:"url(...)",` ??? Where are you stuck? Nothing tried?

Comment: Well, A. Wolff, I tried several lines but since I am not so clever with jQuery, I asked you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add that to the CSS you're applying already.

```
$('<p>').appendTo('#map_div')
        .text('MERCURY')
        .css({position:'absolute',
              top:'100px',
              left:'70px',
             'background-color': 'yellow'
        });
```

or

```
$('<p>').appendTo('#map_div')
        .text('MERCURY')
        .css({position:'absolute',
              top:'100px',
              left:'70px',
              'background-image': 'url(myimage.png)'
         });
```

**Check**: http://jsfiddle.net/zAJvx/48/

Comment: So simple? Thanks! I did try several lines but not thinking this way. I will vote up!

Comment: @Harry FYI, you could use camelCase syntax too: `backgroundImage:"url(...)",`

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is add css class for p element

```
p
{
background-color:rgb(255,0,255);
}
```

Comment: You mean 'rule' not class, right?!

Comment: Add the class as "p" inside your css file.

Comment: "p" is not a class selector, this is what i mean